# Does Magento 2 have batch processing?

Tags: magento2

Does Magento 2 have batch processing? Forgive my ignorance--I'm looking for something similar to Drupal's batch processing. I'm wanting to call a list of operations and batch-processing code usually is more resilient than just calling code outright.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/batch-api/overview

[image]

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: Hey @joseph did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @rob3000, I didn't find answer so far. We're just making restful API calls outright.

Comment: Use following https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/message-queues/implement-bulk.html#createpublisher This is only available in Magento Commerce